# How Do I Create and Initialize a Custom Xamarin Forms Control

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I would like to create a simple custom control (ContentView) in Xamarin Forms that is basically a StackLayout with a variable number of images in it. The idea would be that one could instantiate it in a XAML page like this:

```
 <views:MyControl Pages="4" CurrentPage="2"/>
```

Then, in the code behind I could add an image for each page and set the Source based on the CurrentPage value. However, what I'm not able to figure out is when the values of the attributes become available to affect the layout. In the constructor, Pages and CurrentPage are null.

Where and how do I take attribute values into account when using custom ContentViews?

Comment: The properties of any Xaml should be set after the InitializeComponent() is called on the page. So not quite when it hits the constructor but after that line has run in the page, hence all the controls will have also initialized.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be trying to create something similar to the CarouselPage, which allows you to swipe left and right between pages of content in a similar manner to a gallery.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/carousel-page/

The good news is, that in Forms 2.2 (which is currently in preview and can be obtained via nuget) the CarouselPage class is being replaced by CarouselView, which is awesome because you can now embed it in a page, rather than it being the main page container in itself.

I'd recommend checking out:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/2.2.0.23-pre4

and see if it does what you want.  A quick google suggested that there are already a few tutorials for laying this out springing up on various blogs.